# WPF Custom Control Tab Index

Tags: wpf

I have a custom control in WPF that simply holds a combo box (however I have a few features of it, which is why its sitting inside this custom control.). When I tab through the items and reach it, I can no longer tab anymore. I tried tabbing back and fwd and nothing works. I have this same logic used for a textbox and it works just fine, just the combobox is causing a lockup.

Any ideas how to make it continue tabbing through my UI?

This is a semi dupe of [WPF tab order with custom controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727999/wpf-tab-order-with-custom-controls) however the answer there for C# does not work for me.  It is throwing me the error:
{"PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'ctrlComboBox'."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` property is set to `KeyboardNavigationMode.Contained` when you possible want it to be `KeyboardNavigationMode.Continue`.

Have a read of the MSDN article on Focus, specifically the section on Keyboard Navigation. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx

Comment: That did not solve it, however that did help another issue with IsTabStop not working (used KeyboardNavigation.SetIsTabStop on an Overload of IsTabStop)

Comment: Interesting. It certainly sounded like the focus was getting trapped within the `Combobox`. I will mock up a test tomorrow morning and see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Well not exactly the solution I was looking for, i can detect tab on the combo box's keyup and detect for e.key = 3, then move to next based on coding at MSDN.  Now I am just doing some conditions so it makes sure it has focus (else it detects the up on tab to it) and also reverse tabbing.  Thanks =)

Comment: Goof luck. Focus is one of the most trickiest parts of interface development, especially in WPF.